# Search everyone's Outlook Calender

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I've been asked if it's possible to write an application in C#, preferably ASP.net, that given a date and keyword can search through everyone's Outlook calendar on our Exchange server, and return a list of names.

Is this even possible?
If so, anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Mike